# How to use `GenT` in `hedgehog`

Tags: haskell, property-based-testing, haskell-hedgehog

In the `hedgehog` library, there is a [`GenT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6.1/docs/Hedgehog.html#t:GenT) monad transformer. However the [`forAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6.1/docs/Hedgehog.html#v:forAll) function takes a `Gen` type.

There is a [`forAllT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6.1/docs/src/Hedgehog.Internal.Property.html#forAllT) function, but it is in an `Internal` module.

So if I'd like to use a generator monad transformer with a specific monad (say `State`), what would be the way of making use of such a `GenT`?

Comment: Having `forAllT` as part of the external API seems like a good feature to request from Hedgehog.

Comment: There was actually [a PR for it](https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/pull/206) but it was closed by its author. We *do* consider exposing `forAllT` and `forAllWithT` though.

Comment: I was about to open an issue, but indeed, I saw that [somebody requested this already](https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/issues/208). It seems exposing `forAllT` would be a small change, however I wonder if there are good reasons for keeping this `Internal`.

Comment: Those where added in https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/pull/99/files/. We should have probably exposed them back then.